# Camera parms.set("fast-fps-mode", 1); , disabling capturing screen shot functionality of Camera in SurfaceView

Tags: camera, screenshot, surfaceview

```
 Camera.Parameters parms = mRenderThread.mCamera.getParameters();
                parms.set("fast-fps-mode", 1);    // 1 is 60 fps
                parms.setPreviewFpsRange(60000, 60000);
                CameraUtils.setFocusMode(parms);
                mRenderThread.mCamera.setParameters(parms);
```

When i use this code then it calls OnPictureTaken and returns a bitmap.

```
 Camera.Parameters parms = mRenderThread.mCamera.getParameters();
                parms.set("fast-fps-mode", 0);    // 1 is 60 fps
                parms.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
                CameraUtils.setFocusMode(parms);
                mRenderThread.mCamera.setParameters(parms);
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear

Comment: Actually i am developing an android where user can see real time video preview through camera and i want the user that on double click it capture an snapshots of camera preview that is in a Surfaceview, But when i set frame rate for camera parameters
    parms.set("fast-fps-mode", 0);    // 1 is 60 fps
    parms.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
then it works well and give me bitmap via Camera.captureimage callback but when i use
      parms.set("fast-fps-mode", 1);    // 1 is 60 fps
      parms.setPreviewFpsRange(60000, 60000);
then Camera.captureimage callback  never called.